# SQL Server Geography datatype with .Net Core 2.1

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, sqlgeography, sqlgeometry

I understand that the SQL Server geography and geometry datatypes are not currently supported in .Net EF Core, but I'd still like to use them in standard .Net Core 2.1.  The Microsoft.SqlServer.Types package does not seem to work in Core, at least not as a default install via NuGet.

Is there support for geography in Core directly or as a work-around?  So far, the found references are pre- Core 2.

Comment: There will be a preview of spatial support, check this: https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/308